# Marshmallow permission model

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a question about Marshmallow permission model.
If My app is targeting API level 22 and user installs my app on Marshmallow.
Do I get all permission pre granted?

I did not see this in any of the document.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 3):

> I did not see this in any of the document.

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html):

> If the device is running Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower, *or* the app's `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, the system asks the user to grant the permissions when the user installs the app. If you add a new permission to an updated version of the app, the system asks the user to grant that permission when the user updates the app. Once the user installs the app, the only way they can revoke the permission is by uninstalling the app.

Yes, you get all the permissions at install time. However, the user can still revoke those permissions manually through Settings, and if the user does, while you (generally) will not get a `SecurityException`, you will not get the protected data. For example, if the user revokes your access to contacts, and you try querying for contacts, the system will behave as if there are no contacts.

Comment: Thanks CommonWare, But documentation says user can revoke permission only by uninstalling the app but seems like he can do that even by going into settings

Answer (score 1):

yes you should get all the dangerous permissions pre-granted, but a user can revoke them anytime that may cause instability in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the app requests permissions from the user at run-time. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, so the app needs to check whether it has the permissions every time it runs. For more information about requesting permissions in your app,See this link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html check this developer document